# Limit point of a bounded sequence

Tags: calculus

My textbook says that if $x_n$ is a bounded sequence ($\exists  m,M: m \le x_n \le M$) and a is a limit point of this sequence, then $m \le a \le M$. Can somebody explain why is that so? How can I show that it is true?

Comment: So, let's say $1\leq x_n \leq 2$. Suppose the limit point were, say, $2.1$. By the definition of the limit point, I can find an $x_n$ that is arbitrarily close to $2.1$. For example, I can find an $x_n$ which is at least $0.05$ close to $2.1$, which gives $x_n \geq 2.05$, but that would contradict the fact that $1\leq x_n \leq 2$. The idea of the proof is to formalize this way of thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $a>M$, and let $\epsilon=M-a>0$. The sequence has a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converging to $a$, so by definition there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_{n_k}-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $k\ge m$. Is that actually possible?

Now make a similar argument for $m$.

Comment: So then $|x_n_k − a|< M − a$ whenever k≥m. I can't see, why it's not possible. Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: @Snsn: Draw a picture. Make an axis, mark $M$ somewhere on it, and mark $a$ somewhere larger. Let $\epsilon=M-a$, the distance between $M$ and $a$. Draw the $\epsilon$ ball around $a$, i.e., the interval $a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$. Why can it not contain any term of the sequence?

Comment: One more question: If we suppose that $a \gt M$, shouldn't we let $\epsilon = a - M \gt 0$. Then we get $|x_n_k − a|< a − M$ $\Rightarrow$ $a - x_n_k$ $\lt$ $a -M$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_n_k \gt M$, which contradicts the fact that $m \lt x_n \lt M$.

Comment: @Snsn: Yes, my $M-a$ was a typo that should have been $a-M$. Fortunately, you sorted it out just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the boundedness of the sequence. If $a$ is a limit point of the sequence $x_n$, this means that the values for the sequence $x_n$ get "closer and closer" to $a$. But every single one of those terms has to be at least as big as $m$ but no bigger than $M$. Then it makes sense that $m \leq a \leq M$.

A quick example of that is to take $m=0$ and $M=3$ and let $x_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$. Notice that the first few terms are $\frac{3}{2},1,\cdots$. As $n$ gets bigger the sequence $x_n$ gets closer and closer to the value $\frac{1}{2}$, which is the limit point $a$. But $0 \leq a \leq 3$, same as for our sequence.

Proving that you can find a limit point is a bit more difficult. If $x_n$ is monotone this isn't so bad and you might try to convince yourself of the result. However, in general it requires more and probably isn't a part of your Calculus class. However, if you are interested try reading more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

---